# Is there any shortcut in Visual Studio that implements basic structure of C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In itself, in Visual Studio Code, there is a shortcut (or emmet, not sure if it's called like this) that creates the basic structure of HTML. Typing exclamation mark and pressing TAB bring all the codes that we need to write when we start to build a web application.

However, I am looking for similar shortcut in **Visual Studio Community 2019** that brings starting codes for basic applications in C.

For instance,

```
 include <stdio.h>
 include <stdlib.h>
        
 int main(){

    return 0;
    }
```

P.S. : I know that not every application runs the same starting template or they are not even have a starting template. But, I as a new learner, just writing this structure above all the time so, it is kinda a starting template.

Comment: Visual Studio creates a basic project for `c++` depending on the project type you selected. I don't think there is one for `c`.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `#include <stdio.h>` or `#include <stdlib.h>` should be part of a basic C project. All production level applications I worked with use different ways to read user input, write output or log events. The only code snippet I can find in all applications is `int main(/* even this part is different */) { }`

Comment: Bookmark this page. CTRL-C.  Then CTRL-V.  Done.

Comment: VS and VS Code are very different products. Why do you tag VS when you're asking about VS Code?

Comment: When I read it I thought the person was asking about Visual Studio Community instead of using VSCode since the tags indicated that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) explains how to create your own snippets

Those are the steps on macOS:

- Select **User Snippets** under **Code > Pereferences**
  [image: Menu screenshot]
- Select the **C** language
- Create the snippet in the JSON file

A snippet generating the basic structure of a program could look like this:

```json
{
    "Skeleton": {
        "prefix": "main",
        "body": [
            "#include <stdio.h>",
            "#include <stdlib.h>",
            "",
            "int main(void)",
            "{",
            "\t${1:code}",
            "\treturn 0;",
            "}",
            ""
        ],
        "description": "Dummy C program skeleton"
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Snippet demo]

Answer (score 0):

Take enough time to understand the answer before ignorantly under-voting.

There isn't an out-of-the-box shortcut for C snippets.
However, you can create your own snippets or install this extension from the market.

Name: C Snippets
Id: harry-ross-software.c-snippets
Description: Snippets for the C programming language
Version: 1.3.0
Publisher: Harry Ross Software
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Harry-Ross-Software.c-snippets

[click to see image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWAfz.png)

you can check all available snippets by pressing ctrl+space together